# Fatal error in PMPI_Bcast: Invalid communicator

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to broadcast to a group of processes but I'm getting the following error when I run the code (compiling shows no errors):

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Bcast: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Bcast(1525): MPI_Bcast(buf=0xbfbf1510, count=1, MPI_INT, root=0, MPI_COMM_NULL) failed
PMPI_Bcast(1466): Null communicator
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank,size,b=0;
    MPI_Comm comm_a;
    MPI_Group group_world,new_group;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &group_world);
    MPI_Group_incl(group_world, 4, members, &new_group);
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &comm_a);

    MPI_Bcast(&b,1,MPI_INT,0,comm_a);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile as it is right now so I guess it's a bit hard to tell you what's wrong in the actual one (assuming this was an attempt at making a reduced version).

However, I'll still make a wild guess and suppose that `members` only includes a subset of the processes of `group_world`. Furthermore, I'll also guess that your call to `MPI_Bcast()` is really as you posted...

If I'm correct in my assumptions, then the reason for the error reported is that for the process(es) not listed inside `members`, `MPI_Comm_create()` will return `MPI_COMM_NULL` for `comm_a`. Therefore, when you use it in `MPI_Bcast()`, your receive the error reported.

To avoid this, either use `MPI_Comm_split()` which is way better that `MPI_Comm_create()`, or enclose you call to `MPI_Bcast()` inside an `if` statement checking that `a_comm` isn't `MPI_COMM_NULL`